# Whenever a link is clicked content to the ngcontainer of that link should take over the modal but how to do it with mutiple ngcontainers?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-directive

I have a modal and inside it i have a stepper which is connected to some links, what i want to do is whenever a person clicks on the link the content of that link should be displayed which are defined inside ngcontainers each link have contents of their own and when their respective link is clicked the content of that ngcontainer should only display!
Here's what i am doing now but how do i alter the ngIf in the first parent ngcontainer when i would have multiple ngcontainers for the links?

```html
<div>
<div class="modal-header lead">
    Generate Reports
</div>
<div>
    <ul class="timeline w-75">
        <li class="bg-info">
            <div class="timeline-item">
                <span class="timeline-icon material-icons text-info">brightness_1</span>
                <span class="text-dark">Select Report</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li [ngClass]="isSecondStep?'bg-info':'bg-secondary'">
            <div class="timeline-item">
                <span class="timeline-icon material-icons"
                [ngClass]="isSecondStep?'text-info':'text-secondary'">brightness_1</span>
                <span class="text-dark">Generate Report</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<ng-container *ngIf="!isSecondStep">
        <div>
            <h4><a (click)="isSecondStep=!isSecondStep" class="text-link text-main">Head/Approver Report</a></h4>
            <a>A report containing list of all departments along with it's heads and approvers.</a>
            </div><br>
        <div>
            <h4><a href="#" class="text-link text-main">Student Dues Application Status Report</a></h4>
            <a>A report containing list of all departments along with it's head and approvers.</a>
        </div><br>
        <div>
            <h4><a href="#" class="text-link text-main">Student Details Report</a></h4>
            <a>A report containing all relevant details pertaining to students registers in this institute for the current</a>
        </div><br>
        <div>
            <h4><a href="#" class="text-link text-main">Staff/Faculty Details Report</a></h4>
            <a>A report containing all relevant details pertaining to staff/Faculty of your institute.</a>
        </div><br>
        <div>
            <h4><a href="#" class="text-link text-main">Dues Details Report</a></h4>
            <a>A report containing the details related to total accumulated dues.</a>
        </div><br>    
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="isSecondStep">
        <div>
            <h4><a class="text-main">Head/Approver Report</a></h4>
        </div><br>
        <div class="text-left">
            <label class="mt-1">Scope</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 radio">
                        <label class="text-secondary vertical-center">
                        <input type="radio" class="mr-1" name="scope">Institute</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 radio">
                        <label class="text-secondary vertical-center">
                        <input type="radio" class="mr-1" name="scope" checked>Department</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div><br>
        <div>
            <label class="mt-1 text-left">Department</label><br>
            <select>
                <option [ngValue]="null">Select Department</option>
                <option [ngValue]="dept.id" *ngFor="let dept of departments">{{dept.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div><br>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
            <div class="p-4">
                <span class="material-icons text-main">get_app</span>
                <div class="text-link text-main text-left">Download</div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-4">
                <span class="material-icons text-main">print</span>
                <div class="text-link text-main text-left">Print</div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-4">
                <span class="material-icons text-main">clear</span>
                <div class="text-link text-main text-left">Close</div>
            </div>
        </div>
</ng-container>
</div>
```